# MySQL - CAST json extracted data as time

Tags: mysql, json, datetime

Is there some way to compare hours when extracting from JSON type of data?

Currently I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT clinics.id as cid, clinics.lat, clinics.lng, clinics.opening_hours,
clinics.logo, clinics.address, clinics.city, clinics.state, clinics.name, clinics.description,
clinics.zip, clinics.phone_number, clinics.email, clinics.url, clinics.bookmark_url,
clinics.marker, timezone,
countries.full_name AS country,
(6378 * acos(
cos(radians(-33.8688197)) * cos(radians(lat)) *
cos(radians(lng) - radians(151.2092955)) +
sin(radians(-33.8688197)) * sin(radians(lat))))
AS distance
FROM clinics
JOIN countries ON countries.id = clinics.country_id
LEFT JOIN clinics_services ON clinics.id = clinics_services.clinic_id
WHERE CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."wednesday-to"') as time) > CAST('09:00' as time)
GROUP BY clinics.id
) AS distances
WHERE distance < 5
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

If I run this query I am getting proper results:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."wednesday-to"') FROM clinics
```

(results):

```
"17:30"
"19:00"
"12:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"19:00"
"18:00"
"19:00"
"18:00"
"18:00"
"18:00"
"18:00"
"18:00"
"19:00"
```

But if I try to cast it to time (with this query), I am getting NULL:

```
SELECT CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."wednesday-to"') as TIME) FROM clinics
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(...))` function to strip the literal double-quotes out of a value you have extracted. Or else just store your data in a normalized fashion, and forget about JSON. Virtually every time I've seen questions about JSON in MySQL, it would have been solved more easily by storing data in individual columns.

Comment: if you are sure about your data format, you can do just `JSON_EXTRACT(\`opening_hours\`, '$."wednesday-to"') > '09:00'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem @BillKarwin is right. You need to wrap `JSON_EXTRACT` with `JSON_UNIQUOTE`.

[Chaining JSON_EXTRACT with CAST or STR_TO_DATE fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742801/chaining-json-extract-with-cast-or-str-to-date-fails)

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nomb47TQ2Rxaw5MGc1WtSs/0

```
SELECT CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT('{"hour":"10:00"}','$.hour')) as time) > CAST('09:00' as time);
```

In your case:

```
...
WHERE CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`opening_hours`, '$."wednesday-to"')) as time) > CAST('09:00' as time)
...
```