# Querying records before a date from a JSON item's date in a JSON column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, date-formatting, json-extract

I am querying from a JSON field in the MySQL database which seems to work okay so far. It gives me records. But my issue is that I can't select where an item date in the JSON string is before a certain date. It seems to give me records before and after the given date, which it clearly doesn't  seem to work. This is the code I have so far below: -

```
select 
user_id, 
json_extract(user_profile, "$.gender") as gender, 
json_extract(user_profile, "$.dateofbirth") as dateofbirth
from user_profiles 
where json_extract(user_profile, "$.gender") = "Female" 
and json_extract(user_profile, "$.dateofbirth") < "06/15/1988"
```

I considered using I considered using DATE_FORMAT() eg: -

```
where json_extract(user_profile, "$.gender") = "Female"
date_format(json_extract(user_profile, "$.dateofbirth"), "%d/%m/%Y") < "06/15/1988"
```

but then that just leaves me with no record.
Is there any way to do this so MySQL can understand the date format from the JSON string that I am querying?

Comment: _Possibly a silly question_ What format is the date in the dateofbirth column on the database

Comment: The format is dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that dates in the json document are stored in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, then you want:

```
where 
    json_unquote(user_profile->"$.gender") = 'Female'
    and str_to_date(json_unquote(user_profile->"$.dateofbirth"), '%d/%m/%Y') < '1988-06-15'
```

Or:

```
where 
    json_unquote(user_profile->"$.gender") = 'Female'
    and str_to_date(user_profile->"$.dateofbirth", '"%d/%m/%Y"') < '1988-06-15'
```

`str_to_date()` converts the formated string to a `date`, that you can then compare with your fixed date.

Note: MySQL understands the `->` notation, that can be used a shortcut for `json_extract()`.

Comment: Thanks. That really helped. I wasn't getting any results, but I added json_unquote() to your query and it worked for me. I would appreciate your feedback

Comment: @JamLizzy101: ah yes you are correct... We need `json_unquote()` to remove the quotes around the string that is returned by the JSON extrction. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to make more sense from the answer from GMB. Thanks a lot.
I was still getting no records, but I managed to get it working from what GMB provided by adding json_unquote() from the following Stackoverflow post: [Chaining JSON_EXTRACT with CAST or STR_TO_DATE fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742801/chaining-json-extract-with-cast-or-str-to-date-fails)

The SQL now looks like this: -

```
select 
user_id, 
json_unquote(user_profile->'$.gender') as gender, 
json_unquote(user_profile->'$.dateofbirth') as dateofbirth
from tipanel.user_profiles
where 
user_profile->"$.gender" = 'Female'
and str_to_date(json_unquote(user_profile->'$.dateofbirth'), "%d/%m/%Y") < '1988-06-15';
```

Comments are welcome if this can be done better.