# How to Query Mysql text column

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have mysql 'text' column with data as json which looks like below, how to query using specific value, where Banking is model name , info is field name

```
Banking 
  info : text

info: {"age": 23, name: "John"}
```

Comment: You may need to write SQL inside your activer record request see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: Hey @lacostenycoder thanks for response but it seems its only applicable for field which has mysql json type, in my case it is text type

Comment: may try cast? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html also maybe something helpful here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742801/chaining-json-extract-with-cast-or-str-to-date-fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you can try search by LIKE query as below but because your database save data by text so it is very difficult to handle exception case. So I think you should try use json type of mysql or split it into table and save age as integer.

```
select * from bankings where info LIKE '%"age": 23%'
```

Ruby

```
Banking.where('infor LIKE ?', '%"age": 23%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ActiveRecord to perform this query using `->>` operator:

```
Banking.where("info ->> 'name' = 'John'")
```

Comment: It did not worked , given syntax error, tried the same which you had suggested @matanco

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '>'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [bankings].* FROM [bankings] WHERE (info ->> ''account_type'' = ''card'')'

Comment: could you please share reference about this operator '->> ' in Activerecord guides or any reference